# Plugin Before Onepage Dispatch

Tags: magento2.2, controllers, plugin, before-plugin

I have the following plugin:

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Plugin;

class DisableLoginCheckout
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Group
     */
    protected $customerGroupCollection;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
     */
    protected $redirectFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
     */
    protected $redirectInterface;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Group $customerGroupCollection,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $redirectFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirectInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_customerGroupCollection = $customerGroupCollection;
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $redirectFactory;
        $this->redirect = $redirectInterface;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public function beforeDispatch(
        \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ){
        if ($this->getCustomerGroup() == 'Disabilitato') {

            $lastCustomerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId();
            $this->_customerSession->logout()->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->redirect->getRefererUrl())
                ->setLastCustomerId($lastCustomerId);

            //$this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage(__('Your account has not been enabled yet'));

            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setPath('accuontdisabled', ['_secure' => true]);
            $result = $resultRedirect;

            return $result;
        }
    }

    public function getCustomerGroup()
    {
            $currentGroupId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
            $collection = $this->_customerGroupCollection->load($currentGroupId);

            return  $collection->getCustomerGroupCode();
    }

}
```

when I try to login with authentication-popup i've got this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
>   Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\StoreCheck::beforeDispatch() must
>   implement interface Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface, instance
>   of Magento\Store\App\Response\Redirect given

Any help?

**EDIT**

Company/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage">
        <plugin name="MyPlugin" type="Company\Module\Plugin\DisableLoginCheckout" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**EDIT 2**

before plugin cannot be used in this way, after plugin solves.

Comment: Please update your `di.xml` also..

Comment: @ToanNguyen check edit in question, please

Comment: Please answer your question and mark the answer as accepted if you have found the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plugin implementation is fine. However, the return value is a controller of type redirect.

Subsequently, when the **dispatch** function kicks in after your plugin, it receives a redirect object and that's why you have this error.

Instead, I would try an around plugin myself so that you can keep a similar implementation but with the idea not to break the **dispatch** function anymore.

Comment: For my need after plugin was enough. But if you need to modify input parameters then around plugin is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

before plugin cannot be used in this way, after plugin solves.